# How to use PDO for chunk update with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I've got a problem with my code in Laravel. 
My goal is to update a certain amount of records (products here),I need to update every column in my table and of course I don't know which row I should update in advance. So, to perform my update in the fewer calls to my database,  I decided to use the `case when` syntax in a string. I need to run my query every 50th products updated. (So to be clear, I have a huge string which contains the instruction to update 50 records).

To run my query I use `DB::update(DB::raw($query));` 
where $query is  my string containing my instruction. 
The problem I have is that I don't know how to use the PDO to protect my query  against sql injections. I've read many articles/SO posts but didn't find anything interesting. I wanted to know if you have any idea how to do so and I'd be glad to know them :)

**EDIT** : Sorry forgot to specify that my data are in an array I constructed from users data which I retrieved either in an Excel file or in a URL (Google Shopping if you know it)

My code `

```
public function update_products($products_updated){
        $update_correct = true;
        $query = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($products_updated); $i++){
            $query = 'UPDATE customers_products SET product_long_name= CASE id ';

            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_long_name',$query);
            $query .= 'END, product_name = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_name',$query);

            $query .= 'END, product_unit = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_unit',$query);

            $query .=  'END, product_manufacturer = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_manufacturer',$query);

            $query .=  'END, product_attribute_1 = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_attribute_1',$query);

            $query .=  'END, product_attribute_2 = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_attribute_2',$query);

            $query .=  'END, product_attribute_3 = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_attribute_3',$query);

            $query .=  'END, product_barcode = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_barcode',$query);

            $query .=  'END, product_price = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_price',$query);

            $query .=  'END, product_promo_price = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_promo_price',$query);

            $query .= 'END, product_condition = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'product_condition',$query);

            $query .=  'END, page_url = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'page_url',$query);

            $query .=  'END, user_updated_id = CASE id ';
            $query = $this->foreach_update($products_updated,'user_updated_id',$query);

            $query .= 'END WHERE id IN (';

            foreach($products_updated as $insert){
                $query .= ''.$insert['id'].',';
            }

            $query = rtrim($query,', ');
            $query .= ')';
            if($i % 50 == 0 && $i != 0)
               $update_correct =  DB::update(DB::raw($query));

           if(!$update_correct)
               break;
        }
        if($query != '')
            $update_correct = DB::update(DB::raw($query));

        return $update_correct;
}

private function foreach_update($products_updated,$column,$query){
    foreach($products_updated as $insert){
        if(($column == 'product_promo_price' && !is_numeric($insert[$column])) || !isset($insert[$column]) )
            $query .= 'WHEN '.$insert['id'].' THEN NULL ';
        else
            $query .= 'WHEN '.$insert['id'].' THEN '.DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote($insert[$column]).' ';

    }
    return $query;
}`
```

By the way `DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote(...)` doesn't protect against sql injection. It just adds a \ before single quote

```
UPDATE customers_products SET product_long_name= CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Fuisse gloria pervenisse quo est tamen quam domum videatur inferos diebus Latinis diebus talis abstulit.' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Delatumque perspicabilis nobilitat Iovis eius eo abstractum dolorum Africae Iovis filius vero Mopsi vel quidam.' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Alii abdita duplici fingentes Nemesim omnia vel circulo duplici definiunt praemiatrix quoddam utinam veteres praemiatrix.' WHEN 8911 THEN 'yfrgf' WHEN 9106 THEN 'dfv' END, product_name = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'oui  ?' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN 'dfhbv' WHEN 9106 THEN 'sdfv' END, product_unit = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN 'dhfbv' WHEN 9106 THEN 'sdv' END, product_manufacturer = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN 'hdfbv' WHEN 9106 THEN 'sd' END, product_attribute_1 = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN 'hdfbv' WHEN 9106 THEN NULL END, product_attribute_2 = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN NULL WHEN 9106 THEN NULL END, product_attribute_3 = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN NULL WHEN 9103 THEN NULL WHEN 8911 THEN NULL WHEN 9106 THEN NULL END, product_barcode = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN 'fdbhf' WHEN 9106 THEN 'sdf' END, product_price = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN '82' WHEN 9100 THEN '59' WHEN 9103 THEN '30' WHEN 8911 THEN '120' WHEN 9106 THEN '12' END, product_promo_price = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN NULL WHEN 9100 THEN NULL WHEN 9103 THEN NULL WHEN 8911 THEN '14.2' WHEN 9106 THEN '10' END, product_condition = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN 'hvbad' WHEN 9106 THEN 'sdg' END, page_url = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN 'Test1' WHEN 9100 THEN 'Test2' WHEN 9103 THEN 'Test3' WHEN 8911 THEN 'dhfvb' WHEN 9106 THEN 'dfg' END, user_updated_id = CASE id WHEN 9097 THEN '1' WHEN 9100 THEN '1' WHEN 9103 THEN '1' WHEN 8911 THEN '1' WHEN 9106 THEN '1' END WHERE id IN (9097,9100,9103,8911,9106)
```

Here is the query that will be executed. I know how to use the PDO for basic query but for something constructed like I did,this doesn't work (or I don't know how to use it)

Comment: The document is very clear, you will get all you need: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#updates

Comment: @Gabriel I've already read Laravel documentation (multiple times to be honest) but here I have to specify my variables for the prepared statement. You know, the ' set something = ?', ['dataName'] but I'm using a string. So how can I specify this ?

Comment: Laravel Eloquent does the sql injection prevention by itself, which you do not have to bind query like PDO

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PDO named parameters to protect against SQL Injections.

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
$affected = DB::update('update users set votes = 100 where name = :name', ['name' => 'John']);
```

Further documentation and examples are on the Laravel Official documentation page at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries

Comment: Well I'm using variable for my column names. So can I do something like `$query .= 'WHEN :id THEN :'.$column.' ';` ? And then add an array in my `DB::update(DB::raw($query),['id' => $insert['id'],'product_name' => $insert['product_name']); ` ? And shit that's ugly af